# Display accent character ignoring the extra backward slash

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string with accent character with an extra backward slash.

```
const name = "V\\u00E1ci"
console.log(name); // prints  "V\u00E1ci"
```

I am finding it hard to display it properly, tried various combination of string replace, searched web. but no luck :(

Is there any way I can convert above name to display properly ignoring the first extra backward slash?

This is how, it should be displayed.

```
Váci
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can convert above name to display properly ignoring the first extra backward slash?

You can run the string through the **JSON Parser**, using `JSON.parse()`.

**Working Example:**

```js
const processString = (myString) => {

  myString = JSON.parse('"' + myString + '"');
  
  return myString;
}

console.log(processString('V\\u00E1ci'));
```

---

**Why does this work?**

Simply because when you convert a Javascript string into a JSON string, the **JSON Parser** will automatically convert any code point escape sequences into the corresponding Unicode characters.

Comment: Woow, great Rounin, it works. One more request, if you can also put some explanation to this answer, how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

It's not extra backwards slash in the string. the first \ is a escape character, so that you can add othervice not allowed characters in a string:

```
const s = "\"\""  // """"
```

What you need to do is to replace string '\u00E1' with the characer á. Like this

```
const name2 = name.replace("\\u00E1", "\u00E1"); // Váci
```

You can use the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/unescape-js to do this.

Comment: This will require mapping for each character. Is there any other way?

Comment: I bet someone has already solved this and has a npm package for just this.

Comment: Maybe try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/unescape-js